# JBoss 6 migration: error deploying grails app

Tags: grails, jboss, cxf, jboss6.x

I am attempting to deploy a war (a grails 1.3.7 app) to an jboss 6 which had been in a jboss 5 environment.  The war is not dependent on jboss services or j2ee (it could have been deployed straight to tomcat).  When deploying to jb6, I get the following error message:

```
14:54:17,281 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: 
name=vfs:///opt/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/jbossweb-standalone/deploy/pip.war 
state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: 
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: 
vfs:///opt/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/jbossweb-standalone/deploy/app.war
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.0.GA]
     ...
     ...
     ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Neither any mapped-name/lookup/jndi-name 
specified nor any ResourceProvider could process resource-env-ref named env/cxf 
of type org.apache.cxf.Bus
```

It seems as though JBoss support services are not able to get created, but don't see any underlying problems preventing the service creation.  Also some other web apps are deployed to this instance of jboss, so the overall installation is "sound".  I've done some investigation, but not sure where to go next.  Any ideas as or pointers as to the likely problem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with JNDI, you have a reference to a JNDI in your project, more than likely your web.xml, this resource is not defined as a service in your Jboss server deploy directory, for instance a jdbc.xml definition you are relying on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The problem was that JBoss was using JNDI and the application was pulling a maven dependency for associated with eh Apache CFX project.  The jar file was then interfering withe the JBoss version.